# Encoding problem using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have a demo web application that creates users. When I try to insert data in other languages (like french) the characters are not encoded correctly.  The code on the controller is:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create.htm", params={"id"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String edit(@RequestParam("id") Long id, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("id is " + id);
        User user = userService.get(id);

        model.put("user", user);
        return "user/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result) {

        System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
        System.out.println(user.getLastName());


        validator.validate(user, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            return "user/create"; 
        }

        userService.save(user);
        return "redirect:list.htm";
    }
```

my web.xml is:

```
...

    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

...
```

and the page is:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

...

<form:form method="post" commandName="user">

...

<form:input path="firstName" cssErrorClass="form-error-field"/>

...
```

when I enter some french characters in the first name then the output from the `system.out.println` is `????+?????` or something similar.

I saw other people fixing this with the `CharacterEncodingFilter` but this doesn't seem to work.

Thanks a lot.

Edited the filter value.

Comment: yes you are right, I was testing various things and forgot to edit it again. The problem is the same though

Answer (score 11):

Try making CharacterEncodingFilter the first filter in web.xml.

I realize this question is a little old, but I just ran into the same problem, and moving CharacterEncodingFilter fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

If this still does not work and you're using Tomcat as your application server try to set the following option on every `<Connector>` element in the `server.xml`:

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ...>
    ...
</Connector>
```

This did the trick for me. There might be similar options for other application servers, so you might want to check the server documentation.

Comment: This fixed the same problem for me

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but if the page-encoding in your JSP is "UTF-8", shouldn't the encoding in your CharacterEncodingFilter be UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-7?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add accept-charset="UTF-8" to your form.

Answer (score 0):

Output of `System.out.println()` depends on console encoding, so it's not a good way to debug encoding problems.

To check that your values are decoded properly, you should show it at another page. Actually, it's already done in the case of form validation failure, so your system works fine if values in the fields remains the same after validation error.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to help:

1. In your `setenv.sh` file add `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=utf-8"`
2. In the script that starts your tomcat process, set the LANG environment: `export LANG='utf-8'`

This can then be tested by examining the default character set: `Charset.defaultCharset()`.