# How to handle "ñ" in spring controller?

Tags: spring, character-encoding, special-characters

Hi I have a very big problem. In my jsp page I encode my parameter using javascript function `encodeURIComponent`. I really a problem with `ñ` character. In my jsp the encoded value is`%C3%B1`. In my controller its `Ã±`. I don't know who does the conversion between jsp and controller. In my controller, Im expecting the encoded value which is `%C3%B1`.

Comment: Did you set all source file encodings to UTF-8?

Comment: @Thilo Yes the jsp is `UTF-8`

Comment: Take a look to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958497/980472