# Spring Jersey Corrupts Binary Data

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have a controller like that:

```
@POST
@Path("/{mon}/update")
public Response update(@PathParam("mon") String mon, @QueryParam("er") String er, @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, String data) {
    ...
}
```

When I send XML or JSON data there is not a problem. However when I send binary data I see that data is corrupted. I had a character encoding chain for UTF-8 and I removed it but problem did not resolved.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've detect the problem. I've changed my controller as like that and converted my variable into String if needed:

```
@POST
@Path("/{mon}/update")
public Response update(@PathParam("mon") String mon, @QueryParam("er") String er, @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, byte[] data) {
    ...
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "corrupted" ?

Comment: When I look at data variable I see that bytes are changed (not equal with original bytes of data that I post into my controller)

Comment: Spring CharacterEncodingFilter? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958497/encoding-problem-using-spring-mvc

Comment: @JoopEggen as I mentioned I had a character encoding chain for UTF-8 and I removed it but problem did not resolved.