# URI encoding on JBoss and Spring application

Tags: java, spring, servlets, jboss, modelattribute

We are developing a Spring application which run on JBoss. I've just discovered a problem with characters encoding and @ModelAttribute and @RequestBody annotations when we are sending requests via GET method described in:

- [Encoding problem using Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958497/encoding-problem-using-spring-mvc)
- http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/74209-responsebody-and-utf-8

and possible solution:

- http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q2
- https://developer.jboss.org/message/643825#643825
- https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html

In general we added:

```
<system-properties>
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
  <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.USE_BODY_ENCODING_FOR_QUERY_STRING" value="true"/>
```

to `standalone.xml` file on JBoss and this solved the issue.

We just thinking if there is any possibility to keep this properties in our application and use them when needed instead of changing JBoss configuration? Or maybe you know other working solution on the application side instead of server side?

Comment: Customize spring servlet behaviour, but then you wont have an easy upgrade. So changes better be on server side. Also when server is doing it why you want to add extra code. Any reason? Also in the posts that you suggested they are giving some solutions didnt they work?

Comment: Suggested solution didn't work. I do not have simple access to all JBosses on all our environments so I would like to have this done server-independent.